# Joining MySQL Tables and Calculating Counts - Output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, subquery

I am trying to query a MySQL database of available computers in a busy public computer lab. I have two tables, COMPUTERS and COMPUSE. The COMPUSE table is updated each time a user logs on or signs off a computer. When the logofftime is null, the computer is in use. In this example, Computers 1, 2, 3, and 8 are in use. Computers 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 are available.

```
|-----------------------|-----------------------|----------|-----------|
|       logontime       |       logofftime      |   recID  | compname  |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|----------|-----------|
|  2011-05-13 13:45:16  |             <<null>>  |  310052  |  Comp001  |
|  2011-05-13 13:35:18  |  2011-05-13 13:39:37  |  310043  |  Comp001  |
|  2011-05-13 12:12:09  |  2011-05-13 12:33:37  |  309979  |  Comp001  |
|  2011-05-13 13:00:57  |             <<null>>  |  310018  |  Comp002  |
|  2011-05-13 11:30:13  |  2011-05-13 12:58:15  |  309940  |  Comp002  |
|  2011-05-13 09:36:15  |  2011-05-13 09:47:22  |  309850  |  Comp002  |
|  2011-05-13 09:25:29  |             <<null>>  |  309840  |  Comp003  |
|  2011-05-13 08:45:38  |  2011-05-13 09:24:03  |  309793  |  Comp003  |
|  2011-05-12 22:39:58  |  2011-05-13 00:36:31  |  309640  |  Comp003  |
|  2011-05-13 12:06:22  |  2011-05-13 12:50:23  |  309972  |  Comp004  |
|  2011-05-13 11:10:16  |  2011-05-13 12:01:16  |  309915  |  Comp004  |
|  2011-05-13 07:17:18  |  2011-05-13 09:42:10  |  309731  |  Comp004  |
|  2011-05-13 11:51:38  |  2011-05-13 12:15:35  |  309959  |  Comp005  |
|  2011-05-13 08:55:14  |  2011-05-13 09:47:48  |  309807  |  Comp005  |
|  2011-05-12 18:15:05  |  2011-05-12 18:15:16  |  309502  |  Comp005  |
|  2011-05-13 12:08:40  |  2011-05-13 13:16:41  |  309974  |  Comp006  |
|  2011-05-13 11:29:09  |  2011-05-13 12:05:56  |  309939  |  Comp006  |
|  2011-05-13 11:10:41  |  2011-05-13 11:19:14  |  309916  |  Comp006  |
|  2011-05-13 10:45:27  |  2011-05-13 11:16:44  |  309896  |  Comp007  |
|  2011-05-13 09:21:42  |  2011-05-13 09:55:48  |  309839  |  Comp007  |
|  2011-05-13 08:23:33  |  2011-05-13 09:14:24  |  309770  |  Comp007  |
|  2011-05-13 13:54:12  |             <<null>>  |  310058  |  Comp008  |
|  2011-05-13 13:38:53  |  2011-05-13 13:39:23  |  310045  |  Comp008  |
|  2011-05-13 10:13:23  |  2011-05-13 13:26:51  |  309878  |  Comp008  |
|  2011-05-13 12:16:06  |  2011-05-13 13:26:21  |  309984  |  Comp009  |
|  2011-05-13 10:13:09  |  2011-05-13 12:15:13  |  309877  |  Comp009  |
|  2011-05-13 08:23:22  |  2011-05-13 10:07:08  |  309769  |  Comp009  |
|  2011-05-13 13:45:51  |  2011-05-13 13:47:11  |  310053  |  Comp010  |
|  2011-05-13 11:18:12  |  2011-05-13 13:19:59  |  309925  |  Comp010  |
|  2011-05-13 07:28:50  |  2011-05-13 09:50:09  |  309737  |  Comp010  |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|----------|-----------|
```

This data needs to be joined with a table that indicates which floor of the building the computer is on. That table looks similar to this:

```
|--------|-----------|-------------|
| compID | compname  |   LOCATION  |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
|    95  |  Comp001  |  1st Floor  |
|    96  |  Comp002  |  1st Floor  |
|    97  |  Comp003  |  1st Floor  |
|    98  |  Comp004  |  1st Floor  |
|    99  |  Comp005  |  2nd Floor  |
|   100  |  Comp006  |  2nd Floor  |
|   101  |  Comp007  |  2nd Floor  |
|   102  |  Comp008  |  3rd Floor  |
|   103  |  Comp009  |  3rd Floor  |
|   104  |  Comp010  |  3rd Floor  |
|--------|-----------|-------------|
```

The first table, COMPUSE, has several thousand records in it as it is used for calculating usage statistics for the lab. I need to create an output of how many computers are available on each level. I don't know how to join location from the COMPUTERS table to compname from the COMPUSE table without disrupting my query. Initially, I ran the following query to determine the total number of computers available, but I really need to be able to break it down by area of the building.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(compname) 
        FROM compusage.computers) - 
    (SELECT COUNT(compname) 
        FROM compusage.compuse 
        WHERE logofftime IS NULL)
```

Can anyone help me construct a query that would output the number of available computers on each level of the building? The expected result in this example would be:

```
Level 1:  1 computer (of 4) available
Level 2:  3 computers (of 3) available
Level 3:  2 computers (of 3) available
```

Thanks,
Jordan

UPDATE: This is really similar to what I'm trying to do, but I also can't figure out how to adapt these queries: [PHP::Group and subtract two tables](http://php.bigresource.com/Track/php-Xtns5KON/)

UPDATE 2: This is what I am trying to adapt now, but I don't understand subqueries well enough to get this to work:

```
select (totalcomps.total - inuse.inusecomps) as available, totalcomps.total 
from (SELECT count(compname) as total, location 
         FROM compuse.computers
         GROUP BY location) as totalcomps 
inner join (SELECT count(compname) as inusecomps 
             FROM computers.compuse
             WHERE logofftime is null
             GROUP BY location) as inuse 
on computers.compname = compuse.compname
```

UPDATE 3: I've updated the sample data to be more of a real-world example with more records.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT LOCATION, COUNT(1) as numberOfComps 
FROM COMPUTERS c
   LEFT JOIN COMPUSE cu ON c.COMPNAME = cu.Computer 
WHERE logofftime IS NULL 
GROUP BY LOCATION
```

Comment: Thanks ONe. I'm having the same problem with this query as Brad's. This seems to output the number of computers that are in use. I need to subtract the in-use computers (where logofftime is null) from the master table defining all computers in the building. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks again, ONe. See my comments to Brad below. Logofftime cannot be set to IS NOT NULL, because there are several thousand records in the table -- one for each time a computer is used.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to get the number of FREE computers which are marked with null in that table. I reproduced your tables, and executing my first suggested query (the one with IS NULL), Im getting the expected result, so either you have to explain it again, or you have to check your code :)
Im updating my suggested query to its original state, because it's the one who works.

Comment: Hi ONe. Sorry for my slow reply. I've been out of town. I think you get the expected result because there were exactly four of each (null and not null) in my simplified example. I've updated the example above to better reflect the actual data. (I pulled the last three record from ten computers to better illustrate the problem.) I think by reproducing this table, you'll see what I mean. Also, see my own answer below. I've solved the problem to some extent with PHP, however, I would like to be able to structure a MySQL query to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I did accomplish this task through some PHP calculations based on two separate MySQL queries. This works, but I would prefer to structure an SQL query that does the same thing. Here's the PHP:

```
    <?php
    $username = "user"; $password = "passwd"; $database = "compusage";

    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $inUseQuery = "SELECT location, COUNT(1) as inUseComps 
    FROM compusage.computers
       INNER JOIN compusage.compuse ON computers.compname = compuse.compname
    WHERE logofftime IS NULL
    GROUP BY LOCATION";

    $totCompsQuery="SELECT location, COUNT(compname) as totComps 
    FROM compusage.computers
       GROUP BY LOCATION";

    $result = mysql_query($inUseQuery);
    $inUseNum = mysql_numrows($result);
    $totCompsResult = mysql_query($totCompsQuery);
    $totCompsNum = mysql_numrows($totCompsResult);
    mysql_close();

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $inUseNum) {

    $numCompsInUse=mysql_result($result,$i,"inUseComps");
    $inUseLocation=mysql_result($result,$i,"location");
    $inUseArray[$inUseLocation] = $numCompsInUse;

    $i++;
    }

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $totCompsNum) {

    $totComps=mysql_result($totCompsResult,$i,"totComps");
    $totCompsLocation=mysql_result($totCompsResult,$i,"location");
    $totCompsArray[$totCompsLocation] = $totComps;

    $i++;
    }

    while($totCompsKey = key($totCompsArray)) {
            if (array_key_exists($totCompsKey, $inUseArray)) {
                $availFloor = $totCompsArray[$totCompsKey] - $inUseArray[$totCompsKey];
                if ($availFloor == "1") {
                    printf("<li>%s: %s computer available.</span></li>", $totCompsKey, $availFloor);
                    }
                else {
                    printf("<li>%s: %s computers available.</span></li>", $totCompsKey, $availFloor);
                    }
                }
            else {
                printf("<li>%s: all computers in use.</span></li>", $totCompsKey);
                }
        next($totCompsArray);
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LOCATION, COUNT(compID) as Available 
FROM COMPUTERS C1
INNER JOIN COMPUSE C2 ON C1.COMPNAME = C2.COMPNAME WHERE LOGOFF TIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LOCATION
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Brad. This outputs the number of computers in use, not the number available. Any suggestions for subtracting the in-use computers from those in the COMPUTERS table?

Comment: Changed the query for you to look for IS NOT NULL on LOGOFF field.

Comment: That doesn't work either. The COMPUSE table is dynamically updated over months each time a user logs on or off, so there are thousands of records in that table. When you set _logofftime_ to IS NOT NULL, it includes all the other records and shows nearly 200,000 computers being available! I think there needs to be a way to subtract the count of logged in computers from the total count of computers within the grouping of location. Any thoughts? Thanks for you help!